# Application/framework for effective search in text data from relational database

Tags: search, text-search

I have a relational database (Microsoft SQL Server), that holds text data in one of its tables. Text data are not in the English language. I want to create a new search system that would allow users to effectively search this text data.

I want the ability to perform search queries of some kind, something similar to "google search". I have found out that in SQL Server you can use full-text search queries, where you have proximity, generation terms and others, as is defined here [Microsoft SQL Server full-text search queries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

I would like some advice on an application/framework using different, perhaps better and more capable technologies that would allow me to perform search queries of this kind.

I was thinking about using ElasticSearch, do you think it's the right choice? Would you recommend something different?

Comment: I have not tested this with your environment setup but [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) connects to [MS SQL](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mssql/) and it has a search feature in one of it's [datatable plugins](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/briangann-datatable-panel). So off the top of my head without testing, that is a different application hooked way to search a MS SQL table. I'm not sure it'll be better or more capable but an idea nonetheless.